# Wildcard value in JSONPath

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the below JSON that I am trying to interpret, using json.net.

```
 {    
  "platformUpdateDomain": 0,    
  "platformFaultDomain": 0,    
  "vmAgent": {    
    "vmAgentVersion": "2.5.1198.709",    
    "statuses": [    
      {    
        "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",    
        "level": "Info",    
        "displayStatus": "Ready",    
        "message": "GuestAgent is running and accepting new configurations.",    
        "time": "2015-04-21T11:42:44-07:00"    
      }    
    ]    
  },    
  "disks": [    
    {    
      "name": "myosdisk",    
      "statuses": [    
        {    
          "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",    
          "level": "Info",    
          "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",    
          "time": "2015-04-10T12:44:10.4562812-07:00"    
        }    
      ]    
    }    
  ],    
  "statuses": [    
    {    
      "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",    
      "level": "Info",    
      "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",    
      "time": "2015-04-10T12:50:09.0031588-07:00"    
    },    
    {    
      "code": "PowerState/running",    
      "level": "Info",    
      "displayStatus": "VM running"    
    }    
  ]    
}
```

I wish to extract the Status, where the code contains the below value:

> PowerState

However, I cannot work out how to do this, I can match against the entire string using Json.Net, but I'd like to

```
myJsonJObject.SelectToken("$.statuses[?(@.code == 'PowerState/running')]");
```

However, part of the "code" value can change, so I'd like to try and search based on the below condition

```
myJsonJObject.SelectToken("$.statuses[?(@.code == 'PowerState/*')]");
```

What is the correct Jsonpath expression to do this? Matching against a substring would also work, but again, I cannot find an example to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround is to use linq.

select all the status objects, filter on the code value, which has been converted to a string to use the contains method.

```
var x = myJsonJObject.SelectToken("$.statuses").Where(y => ((string)y.SelectToken("$.code")).Contains("PowerState"));
```